# Resized ImageView in a ViewGroup is not displayed well

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

I have a Customised viewgroup and customized imageViews in it. Using that I can slide from one imageview to another image view in fling gesture.

When scaled ImageView using pinch zoom, some how it is zooming but space according to its zooming is not available in view group.

```
enter code here
public class RealViewSwitcher extends ViewGroup {

public static boolean isAllowedToDispatchTouchEvents=false;

// TODO: This class does the basic stuff right now, but it would be cool to have certain things implemented,
// e.g. using an adapter for getting views instead of setting them directly, memory management and the
// possibility of scrolling vertically instead of horizontally. If you have ideas or patches, please visit
// my website and drop me a mail. :-)

/**
 * Listener for the event that the RealViewSwitcher switches to a new view.
 */
public static interface OnScreenSwitchListener {

    /**
     * Notifies listeners about the new screen. Runs after the animation completed.
     * 
     * @param screen The new screen index.
     */
    void onScreenSwitched(int screen);

}

private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY = 1000;
private static final int INVALID_SCREEN = -1;

private Scroller mScroller;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;

private final static int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
private final static int TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING = 1;

private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;

private float mLastMotionX;
private int mTouchSlop;
private int mMaximumVelocity;
private int mCurrentScreen;
private int mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;

private boolean mFirstLayout = true;

private OnScreenSwitchListener mOnScreenSwitchListener;

public RealViewSwitcher(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RealViewSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    System.out.println("int()");
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());

    final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
    mTouchSlop = configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMaximumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    System.out.println("measured");
    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
    }

    final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
    }

    // The children are given the same width and height as the workspace
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    if (mFirstLayout) {
        scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * width, 0);
        mFirstLayout = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int childLeft = 0;
    System.out.println("Layout set");
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            final int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            child.layout(childLeft, 0, childLeft + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
            childLeft += childWidth;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("TouchEvent", "parent:motion event detected");
    if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
    }
    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final float x = ev.getX();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        Log.d("TouchEvent", "parent:motion event to down");
        /*
         * If being flinged and user touches, stop the fling. isFinished will be false if being flinged.
         */
        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            mScroller.abortAnimation();
        }

        // Remember where the motion event started
        mLastMotionX = x;

        mTouchState = mScroller.isFinished() ? TOUCH_STATE_REST : TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        Log.d("TouchEvent", "parent:motion event to move");
        final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);

        boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;

        if (xMoved) {
            // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
        }

        if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
            // Scroll to follow the motion event
            final int deltaX = (int) (mLastMotionX - x);
            mLastMotionX = x;

            final int scrollX = getScrollX();
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                if (scrollX > 0) {
                    scrollBy(Math.max(-scrollX, deltaX), 0);
                }
            } else if (deltaX > 0) {
                final int availableToScroll = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1).getRight() - scrollX - getWidth();
                if (availableToScroll > 0) {
                    scrollBy(Math.min(availableToScroll, deltaX), 0);
                }
            }
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        Log.d("TouchEvent", "parent:motion event to up");
        if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
            final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
            velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000, mMaximumVelocity);
            int velocityX = (int) velocityTracker.getXVelocity();

            if (velocityX > SNAP_VELOCITY && mCurrentScreen > 0) {
                // Fling hard enough to move left
                snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen - 1);
            } else if (velocityX < -SNAP_VELOCITY && mCurrentScreen < getChildCount() - 1) {
                // Fling hard enough to move right
                snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen + 1);
            } else {
                snapToDestination();
            }

            if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
            }
        }

        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

        Log.d("TouchEvent", "parent:motion event to cancel");
        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
    }

    return true;
}

private void snapToDestination() {
    final int screenWidth = getWidth();
    final int whichScreen = (getScrollX() + (screenWidth / 2)) / screenWidth;

    snapToScreen(whichScreen);
}

private void snapToScreen(int whichScreen) {
    if (!mScroller.isFinished())
        return;

    whichScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));

    mNextScreen = whichScreen;

    final int newX = whichScreen * getWidth();
    final int delta = newX - getScrollX();
    mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, Math.abs(delta) * 2);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {

    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
        postInvalidate();

    } else if (mNextScreen != INVALID_SCREEN) {
        mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(mNextScreen, getChildCount() - 1));

        // notify observer about screen change
        if (mOnScreenSwitchListener != null)
            mOnScreenSwitchListener.onScreenSwitched(mCurrentScreen);

        Log.d("TouchEvent", "parent:motion event to Compute scroll");
        mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the currently displayed screen.
 * 
 * @return The index of the currently displayed screen.
 */
public int getCurrentScreen() {
    return mCurrentScreen;
}

/**
 * Sets the current screen.
 * 
 * @param currentScreen The new screen.
 */
public void setCurrentScreen(int currentScreen) {
    mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(currentScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
    scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * getWidth(), 0);
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Sets the {@link ViewSwitcher.OnScreenSwitchListener}.
 * 
 * @param onScreenSwitchListener The listener for switch events.
 */
public void setOnScreenSwitchListener(OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener) {
    mOnScreenSwitchListener = onScreenSwitchListener;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
{

    Log.d("TouchEvent", "parent:Intercept Touch Event");
    if(isAllowedToDispatchTouchEvents)
    {

    }onTouchEvent(ev);
    return isAllowedToDispatchTouchEvents;

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your last sentence. How about your layout xml? Some code?